# App crashes when I add multiple MenuItems in cocos2d

Tags: ios, menu, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem

It works fine when I add only one MenuItem. but when I go for other two MenuItems it crashes with exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

Here what i am doing

```
    CCMenuItem *startGame = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"start-game.png" selectedImage:@"start-game.png" target:self selector:@selector(startGame:)];


    CCMenuItem *settings = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"settings.png" selectedImage:@"settings.png" target:self selector:@selector(settings:)];


    CCMenuItemImage *gameCentre = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"game-centre.png" selectedImage:@"game-centre.png" target:self selector:@selector(gameCentre:)];


    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:startGame, settings, gameCentre, nil];
    [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];
    [self addChild:menu z:1];
```

here are my selector functions

```
-(void)startGame:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"start game");
 }
-(void)setttings:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"settings");
 }
-(void)gameCentre:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"game centre");
 }
```

Thanx in advance for any help

Comment: you misspelled -(void)setttings:(id)sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your selectors do end with ":", ie @selector(gameCentre:), make sure the methods in your class actually take argument

```
- (void)startGame:(id)sender
{
    // do whatever you want here
}

- (void)settings:(id)sender
{
    // do whatever you want here
}

- (void)gameCentre:(id)sender
{
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: I'have done the same. Strange thing for me is that it doesn't crash on  first line, it crashes on 2nd line

Comment: you misspelled your method, -(void)setttings:(id)sender, it should be - (void)settings:(id)sender

Comment: OMG! sorry for such a stupid mistake. actually its my first exp of game development so i am getting confused. Thanx anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your selector functions (startGame, settings, gameCentre) are not written properly.

Comment: check if your project includes images which you have mentioned in code.

Answer (score 0):

your selector might not taking any parameters and you are mentioning "`@selector(startGame:)`" as if they are taking a parameter. it could be like "`@selector(startGame)`" if they are not accepting any parameter. you need to check that..

Comment: It didn't make any differance.